# JDBC connection cannot connect when there are null dates

Tags: mysql, date, jdbc, libreoffice

Queries to MySQL return the error,

> java.sql.SQLException: Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Date

when accessing database through libreoffice via jdbc.  I have found solutions that recommend the following:

> Edit -> Database -> Properties 
>   Select the "Advanced Properties" tab. 
>   Under "Name of the MySQL database", enter:
>
> `<database_name>?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`

Unfortunately, I am using Libreoffice 4.4 and when I go to the settings location recommended above there is no "Name of the MySQL database" field.  Where to I place the `convertToNull` command so I can access my database?

Comment: If you did use a jdbc url to set up your DB you can append "?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" at the end of the jdbc url

Comment: This worked.  I don't know if I miskeyed the last time but I logged in, did not see new answers so I tried the suggested solution again and this time I was able to connect with no problem.  Thank you!